# wordpress accessing custom fields from post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have looked everywhere and am not finding the answer I'm looking for.

Basically I want to access information from a post and display it on my front page.

I'm using a plugin called Advanced Custom Fields to organize my content for each post.

I can retrieve the post title like this.

```
$post_id = 148;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
?>
<h2><?php echo $queried_post->post_title; ?></h2>
<?php echo $queried_post->field_4f2af94aa1371; ?>
```

But I can not access the value of the custom fields. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump($queried_post)`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the get_post_meta function

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post_id, 'CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME', TRUE ); ?>
```

- first param: post ID
- second param: key (name of the meta value)
- third param: true if you want a single value (instead of array)

For more information; http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta